# jQuery Validation on ajax loaded form

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a from that is loaded from ajax. Now I need to validate that form, but is does not work. Click event work successfully.

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '#save', function (){
    console.log("a");

    $("#qform").validate_popover({
    popoverPosition: 'top',
    submitHandler: function(form) {

    }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: make a fiddle please

Comment: try `$("#qform").validate({  // your code here})`   instead `validate_popover`

Comment: please describe your html DOM elements, so we can help you better..

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and clearly tell us *exactly* which jQuery plugins you're using for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#qform', function (){

 $(this).validate_popover({
   popoverPosition: 'top',
   submitHandler: function(form) {

  }
});
```